# python scipy.stats.binom error "Cannot cast scalar from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'"

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I'm trying to generate binomial distributions with large values of *n*, however if I input values larger than (2^32)/2-1 I get an error. E.g. if I run the following:

```
from scipy.stats import binom
binom.rvs(2147483648,0.5)
```

I get this error:

```
binom.rvs(2147483648, .5)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[4], line 1
    binom.rvs(2147483648, .5)

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\default\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:3357 in rvs
    return super().rvs(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\default\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1048 in rvs
    vals = self._rvs(*args, size=size, random_state=random_state)

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\default\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_discrete_distns.py:62 in _rvs
    return random_state.binomial(n, p, size)

  File mtrand.pyx:3385 in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.binomial

TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

I'm using python as part of an Anaconda installation in Windows 10. The python version is 3.9.16 64-bit, scipy is version 1.10.0.

Some things I've tried to diagnose the problem:

Running the same code in an online interpreter. I ran it on the w3 schools website and it didn't give an error. The scipy version was 1.4.1. I made an Anaconda environment on my PC with the same version of scipy and it *still* gave the error.

Checked other discrete random number distributions. scipy.stats.boltzmann didn't seem to have this limitation. scipy.stats.poisson did throw the error 'lam value too large' when I tried poisson.rvs(lam), where lam is bigger than 2147013648 (i.e. less than (2^32)/2-1 ). Seems like a similar error but not the same.

Could this be a bug in the binomial function? The fact it runs fine on the w3 schools website makes me think it's a configuration issue with my machine but I'm not sure what to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `n` is too large for `np.random.binomial`:

```
In [65]: np.random.binomial(np.array(2147483648),.5)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[65], line 1
----> 1 np.random.binomial(np.array(2147483648),.5)
        np.random = <module 'numpy.random' from 'C:\\Users\\paul\\miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\random\\__init__.py'>
File mtrand.pyx:3385, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.binomial()

TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

That number, as array is `int64`:

```
In [66]: np.array(2147483648)
Out[66]: array(2147483648, dtype=int64)
```

The same number, but as python int, produces a related error:

```
In [67]: np.random.binomial(2147483648,.5)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[67], line 1
----> 1 np.random.binomial(2147483648,.5)
        np.random = <module 'numpy.random' from 'C:\\Users\\paul\\miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\random\\__init__.py'>
File mtrand.pyx:3385, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.binomial()    
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

It's not documented, but apparently the `c` code (or `cython`), expects a `long/int32` as the `n` parameter.

This is for a fairly new `numpy` (1.23.5)

Larger values work for the newer random generators:

```
In [78]: rng=np.random.default_rng()
In [79]: rng.binomial(21474836489,.5)
Out[79]: 10737383445
```

This random generator can be supplied to `binom.rvs`:

```
In [85]: binom.rvs(2147483648, .5, random_state=rng)
Out[85]: 1073724721
```